# Corrupt file ftp ulpoaded with php from localhost (Xampp)

Tags: php, ftp, upload

I tried to send files in FTP from localhost (XAMPP) with this code but the files uploaded are corrupted (the file size is smaller and I can't open the file [img1.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uWC1.png)). 
But if I try the code from a host it works perfectly.
How Can I fix the problem?

```
$server = '**.******';
$username = '*******';
$password = '*******';
print_r($_FILES['fileToUpload']);
$id_connessione = ftp_connect($server);

$login = ftp_login($id_connessione, $username, $password);

$file_originale = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
$file_destinazione = $_POST['nomeUser']."_".$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];

ftp_chdir($id_connessione, '/upload/');

if (ftp_put($id_connessione, $file_destinazione, $file_originale, 
  FTP_ASCII)){
     echo "successfully uploade";

} else {
 echo "problem";
}

ftp_close($id_connessione);
```

Comment: please include your code in the question

Comment: this is the $_FILES array

Array ( [name] => CopertinaCatalogo.pdf [type] => application/pdf [tmp_name] => C:\xampp731\tmp\php8B06.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 708166 ) successfully uploaded

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use `FTP_BINARY` instead of `FTP_ASCII`.

BINARY mode means data is not changed during the transfer, and is what you want to use almost always. The ASCII mode converts line break characters between local and server conventions and is useful only for plain text files.

Comment: Please do not answer so blatantly duplicate questions. Vote them to be closed as duplicate instead.

Comment: First time I've seen this question @Martin

Comment: Thank you very very very much